# How to dynamically interchange the tree view data with changes in its hierarchy being displayed in the data table and everything is drag able

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[image]

Hi, so this tree view data should be drag able and the hierarchal changes should reflect in the database and the data should be bind dynamically. The entire project is in MVC .NET or .NET core

I've implemented some Jquery plugins and implemented the drag and drop function in the frontend but I'm unable to figure out the logic and how to bind data and how the changes would reflect in the database. if anyone has any related link or anyone has already implemented this, please write below, thank you.

Comment: `I've implemented some Jquery plugins and implemented the drag and drop function in the frontend`Maybe you need to pass the updated structure data to backend in your jquery,and then update the db in backend.

Comment: Yeah I implemented it today with a Jquery plugin called as Gijgo, The drag and drop didn't work that well, I had to hardcode for proper implementation, thank you for your response.